# Плохо работают свайпы в RecyclerView в coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, recyclerview, coordinator-layout

У меня есть `СoordinatorLayout` в который вложен appbarlayout. За ним располагается recyclerview,  в котором реализовано удаление пунктов свайпами в право/лево.
Реализовано  с помощью [SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener](https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView).
И всё казалось бы отлично, если бы это не работало так плохо. Карточка из ресайкл удаляется если только провести от края до края экрана и очень аккуратно, в то же время, если создать отдельный layout и  внести туда ресвью, работает всё отлично.
Осознание того, что проблема кроется в том, что свайпы не хотят дружить со скрывающимся эпбаром есть, но как эту проблему можно решить? Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Сам фрагмент:**

```
public class TimeList extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    static private List<Double> time; //список со временем
    private List<String> scr;
    public List<Integer> numb;
    private RecyclerView rv; // опредеяем ресайклевью

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager; // не надо, но пусть будет
    static RVAdapter adapter1;

    static SQLHelper sqlHelper;
    static SQLiteDatabase db;

    //Button delete;
    FloatingActionButton delete;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View w = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

        rv = (RecyclerView) w.findViewById(R.id.rv);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        sqlHelper= new SQLHelper(getActivity());
        db=sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        initializeData(); 
        initializeAdapter(); 


        delete = (FloatingActionButton) w.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);

        SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
                new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(rv,
                        new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {


                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipeLeft(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipeRight(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView 
recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    time.remove(position);
                                    scr.remove(position);
                                    adapter1.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView 
recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    time.remove(position);
                                    scr.remove(position);
                                    adapter1.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
        swipeTouchListener.setEnabled(true);

        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);


        return w;
    }



    private void initializeData() {
        /**
         * инициализируем данные
         */
        time = new ArrayList<>();
        scr = new ArrayList<>();
        numb = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {

        adapter1 = new RVAdapter(time, scr, numb);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    public static void addTime(double t, String scr) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIME, t);
        contentValues.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SCRAMBLE, scr);

        db.insert(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        adapter1.add(t, scr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.delete:

                int size = time.size();
                time.clear();
                scr.clear();
                numb.clear();
                adapter1.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);

                break;
        }
    }


    static List<Double> getList() {
        return time;
    }

}
```

RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.TimeViewHolder> {

    public static class TimeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        /**
         * Класс, в котором определяем отдельные элементе в строке ресайклвью
         * но это не точно
         */

        CardView cv; // 
        public TextView ftime; // время в карточке
        public TextView fdata; // дата сборки
        public TextView fnumber;


        public TimeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            ftime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ftime);
            fdata = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fdata);
            fnumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fnumber);

        }
    }

    List<Double> time; // список со временем
    List<String> scramble;
    List<Integer> numb;
    int position = 0;

    RVAdapter(List<Double> time1, List <String> scramble1,List<Integer> numb) {
        /**
         * конструктор
         */

        this.time = time1;
        this.scramble = scramble1;
        this.numb = numb;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public TimeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        View v = 
            LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, 
viewGroup, false);
        TimeViewHolder pvh = new TimeViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TimeViewHolder timeViewHolder, int i) {

        timeViewHolder.ftime.setText("" + time.get(i));
        timeViewHolder.fdata.setText("" + scramble.get(i));
        timeViewHolder.fnumber.setText("" + numb.get(i) +".");

    }

    public void add(double t, String s) {

        time.add(0, t);
        scramble.add(0, s);
        numb.add(0, Timer.countOfSolves);


        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return time.size();
    }


    public void clear() {
        time.remove(0);
        scramble.remove(0);
        notifyItemRemoved(0);
    }
 }
```

activity_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_scrollInterpolator=
"@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@null">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/del"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена. Recyclerview было вложено в relative layout, который был вложен в nested scrollview. Убрал всё кроме recyclerview, а к нему в xml добавил

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Теперь работает отлично, может кому-нибудь понадобится. А мне скорее всего необходимо лучше изучить coordinator layout